# Loop through array with objects with optional properties but always loop fully

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, interface

I want to iterate through an array of objects defined like this:

```
export interface Incident {
  ID: string;
  userName1?: string;
  userName2?: string;
  userPhoneNumber?: string;
  crashSeverity: number;
  crashTime: number;
}
```

Now I have some sample data like this:

```
  {
    crashID: "CO111111",
    userName1: "TEST",
    userName2: "NAME2",
    userPhoneNumber: "11111",
    crashSeverity: 2,
    crashTime: 1571566666
  },
  {
    crashID: "12345",
    userName1: "TEST",
    crashSeverity: 2,
    crashTime: 1571566666
  }
```

However, I want to save the data to a csv file. For this, I need to always iterate through the whole interface, even if some properties are missing and still write a comma.
Is there a way to iterate through the whole incident interface for each object and not just all the available properties?

Here is an example output:
[image]

My current code:

```
  ConvertToCSV(objArray) {
    const array =
      typeof objArray !== "object" ? JSON.parse(objArray) : objArray;
    let str = "";
    let header = "";

    for (const index in objArray[0]) {
      header += index + ";";
    }
    header = header.slice(0, -1);
    // append Label row with line break
    str += header + "\r\n";

    // loop through every entry
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      let line = "";
      // loop through every row
      for (const firstIndex in array[i]) {
          line += array[i][firstIndex] + ";";
      }
      str += line + "\r\n";
    }
    return str;
  }
```

Comment: Your code seems to have support for 2 levels of nested objects, where `secondIndex` is expected to be numeric. I don't see how this is relevant for your question. Could you simplify the code to just focus on your question?

Comment: @trincot I'm sorry, I forgot to remove it. I removed the unnecessary parts in the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by saving the headers in the .ts and just accessing the values via header names:

```
  headers = [
"crashID",
"userName1",
"userName2",
"userPhoneNumber",
"crashSeverity",
"crashTime"
];

ConvertToCSV(objArray) {
const array =
  typeof objArray !== "object" ? JSON.parse(objArray) : objArray;
let str = "";
const header = this.headers.join(";");
str += header + "\r\n";

// loop through every entry
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  let line = "";
  // loop through every row
  for (const headerElem of this.headers) {
    line += array[i][headerElem];
    line += ";";
  }
  str += line + "\r\n";
}
return str;
}
```

Comment: This is fine, but you added information to the input side of this question.

Answer (score 1):

Interfaces only exist at compile time. They don't exist at run time, so you cannot inspect them with code.

Without that possibility, you could still do something to at least make sure the output CSV is well-formed, i.e. all values appear in their right column.

For this you would need to first inspect the whole data, and collect all used fields. When fields are often lacking, you will need some logic to derive which is the right field ordering. For instance if you have two objects, and the first has only fields "a" and "b", and the second only field "c" and "d", there is no way to know the correct field ordering. It could be "a;b;c;d", or "a;c;b;d", or "c;a;b;d", ...etc. However, if there is also a third object that has fields "b" and "c", then the order is perfectly defined: "a;b;c;d". This is about finding a [topological order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting).

So here is code that first performs such a scan and ordering, and then proceeds to actually encode the data as CSV in a second phase:

```js
function convertToCSV(objArray) {
    const array =
        typeof objArray === "string" ? JSON.parse(objArray) : objArray;
    
    // Iterate the whole array to find any fields
    //    Keep track of which fields have to precede other fields
    const predecessors = new Map;
    for (const obj of array) {
        Object.keys(obj).forEach((key, i, keys) => {
            if (!predecessors.has(key)) predecessors.set(key, new Set);
            if (i) predecessors.get(key).add(keys[i-1]);
        });
    }
    // Sort fields
    const fields = topologicalSort(predecessors);

    return [fields.join(";"), // header line
        ...array.map(obj => fields.map(field => obj[field] || "").join(";")) // data lines
    ].join("\r\n");
}

function topologicalSort(predecessors) {
    const visited = new Set;
    
    function visit(key) {
        if (visited.has(key)) return;
        predecessors.get(key).forEach(visit);
        visited.add(key);
    }
    
    for (let key of predecessors.keys()) visit(key);
    return [...visited];
}

// Sample data
const data = [{
    userName2: "NAME2",
    userPhoneNumber: "11111",
    crashSeverity: 2,
  }, {
    userName1: "TEST",
    crashSeverity: 2,
    crashTime: 1571577777
  }, {
    crashID: "12345",
    userName1: "Mr First",
    userName2: "Second name",
    crashSeverity: 3,
    crashTime: 1571588888
  }];

const csv = convertToCSV(data);
console.log(csv);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I think my solution is more simple but I appreciate your solution.